# Trying to cut and paste data from todays date into a new sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

Have code that generates an output with both today's date as well as the previous date run, i am trying to find a code that would select all information with today's date as the timestamp cut it and paste it into a new sheet.

Example of points on sheet -some columns

| amount_eur | fx_Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 500,000 | 06/22/2023 |
| 550,000 | 06/23/2023 |

Am relatively new to VBA

Have tried

```
Sub Filter_Today()
    '
    'Filter_Today Macro
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("S1").AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    End With
End Sub


Sub AddNewSheetswithNameExample1()
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Today"
End Sub


Sub vba_copy_titles_to_another_worksheet()
    Range("A1:S1").Copy Worksheets("Today").Range("A1")
End Sub


Sub Paste_Range()
    Range("A2:S10000").Cut Worksheets("Today").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

the last sub I was hoping would only cut and paste the visible information but it also selects information filtered out. Was wondering how to get around this in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `SpecialCells` method something like this

```
Sub Paste_Range()
    Range("A2:S10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cut Worksheets("Today").Range("A2")
End Sub
```